How to Implement a Custom Geometry Class for Drawing Great Circle (Orthodrome) in OpenLayers 10?
I’ve encountered an issue while working with OpenLayers 10. I’d like to implement a custom geometry class to allow the user to draw a great circle (orthodrome), but I’m not sure how to do this.
I need the orthodrome to behave like a regular LineString and not be split into segments as if it were drawn using MultiLineString. The drawing algorithm should work as follows:

The user can click on arbitrary points on the map to place points.
If more than one point is placed, they should be connected by a great circle (orthodrome).
The user should be able to add new vertices along the existing orthodrome, and when that happens, the old orthodrome should split into two new great circles.

Is it possible to implement such functionality in OpenLayers? If so, how can I achieve this?
I tried to create a custom geometry class and add it to a Feature. I also defined custom styles for rendering the object, but this didn’t help. After investigating some of the internal workings of OpenLayers, I realized that I end up in the drawCustom function of the Builder class. This class describes the rendering of the built-in geometries provided by OpenLayers on the canvas. Since this method doesn’t have a scenario for rendering fully custom geometries, my renderer function is simply not called.
class Orthodrome extends SimpleGeometry {
  constructor(start, end) {
    super();
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.updateCoordinates();
  }

  updateCoordinates() {
    this.flatCoordinates = this.calculateGreatCircle(this.start, this.end);
    this.changed();
  }

  calculateGreatCircle(startCoord, endCoord) {
    const start = toLonLat(startCoord);
    const end = toLonLat(endCoord);
    const arcGenerator = new arc.GreatCircle({ x: start[0], y: start[1] }, { x: end[0], y: end[1] });
    const arcLine = arcGenerator.Arc(100, { offset: 10 });
    const coords = arcLine.geometries[0].coords.map(coord => {
        return fromLonLat(coord)
    });
    return coords;
  }

  getCoordinates() {
    return this.flatCoordinates;
  }

  setCoordinates(coordinates) {
    this.start = coordinates[0];
    this.end = coordinates[1];
    this.updateCoordinates();
  }

  getType() {
    return 'Orthodrome';
  }
}

export default Orthodrome;

const orthodromeRenderer = (coords, state, map) => {
  const context = state.context;
  const pixelRatio = state.pixelRatio || 1;

  context.beginPath();

  const start = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coords[0]);
  context.moveTo(start[0] * pixelRatio, start[1] * pixelRatio);

  for (let i = 1; i < coords.length; i++) {
    const pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coords[i]);
    context.lineTo(pixel[0] * pixelRatio, pixel[1] * pixelRatio);
  }

  context.strokeStyle = 'blue'
  context.lineWidth = 2 * pixelRatio;
  context.stroke();
};

const customStyle = (map) => new Style({
  renderer: (pixelCoordinates, state) => {
    const geometry = state.geometry;
    if (geometry.getType() === 'LineString' || geometry.getType() === 'Orthodrome') {
      const coords = geometry.getCoordinates();
      orthodromeRenderer(coords, state, map);
    }
  },
});

